# Prove the origin is liapunov stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system is $x'=0, y'=-y$.

I was able to determine that general solutions should have the form $y=y_0 e^{-t}$ and $x(t)=x_0$ where $y_0=y(0), x_0=x(0)$.

I am trying to prove that the origin is liapunov stable but I'm having trouble finding a delta that makes the condition for liapunov stability hold.

Here's my work:

Suppose $\hat{x}(t)$ is a general solution of the system.

$||\hat{x}(t)-0||=\sqrt{x_0^2 +y_0^2 e^{-2t}}$

Then I started looking for an upper bound on this expression so that I can determine the delta needed however I know from Cauchy-Schwarz that

$2|x_0||y_0||e^{-t}| \leq x_0^2 +y_0^2 e^{-2t}$

and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_0|+|y_0||e^-t|)$ $\leq x_0^2 +y_0^2 e^{-2t}$

So I've been able to find lower bounds but no upper ones. Please help. I just need some direction on how to find the upper bound please. Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of the Lyapunov theory. There is no need to solve the system of equations.

Let $V(x) = {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$. Let $x$ solve $x_1' = 0 , x_2' = -x_2$. Let $\phi(t) = V(x(t))$. Then $\phi'(t) = - x_2^2 \le 0$.

In particular, $V(x(t)) \le V(x(0))$ for all $t \ge 0$. let $\epsilon>0$ and choose
$\|x(0)\| < \epsilon$, then $\|x(t)\| \le \|x(0)\| < \epsilon$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you!! I did not have that version of the theorem. I will look further into it.

Comment: Differentiate $\phi(t) = {1 \over 2}(x_1^2(t)+x_2^2(t))$?

Comment: Can you please explain further how you got $′()=−_2^2$

Comment: Have you differentiated $\phi(t)$???

Comment: And what is $x_2'=$?

Comment: Oh my gosh. I'm sorry thank you